# wordpress wp mail not changing sender mail

Tags: email, wp-mail

im using `wp_mail` to create contact page my email var is

```
$subject = 'hello';
$html = 'message here';
$admin_email = 'admin@yahoo.com';
$email = 'email@yahoo.com';
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8','From: SiteName <'.$email.'>');
wp_mail($admin_email,$subject,$html,$headers);
```

but it's not working for me

when i remove `From: SiteName <'.$email.'>` it's working
but i need to change site name and sender email so what is wrong with my code

Comment: try with `"From: sitename <$email>"` you forget the ending `>`

Comment: yes but still not working , thanks